# dplyr group by not working in Shiny

Tags: r, group-by, shiny, dplyr

I am working with R shiny application,in that i have two dropdown boxes. first drop down is populated with categorical variables and second is populated with numerical variables. And then I am applying groupby on categorical variable.
Here is my code.

```
dataset<- dataUpload()

var1 <- as.character(input$variable1)
var2 <- as.character(input$variable2)

v$data <- dataset %>%
  group_by(dataset[,var1]) %>%
  summarize(Sum=sum(dataset[,var2])) %>%
  arrange(desc(Sum))
```

And it gives me following output.

```
 Source: local data frame [7 x 2]

  dataset[[var1]]                Sum
           (fctr)               (int)

1     Chicken Biryani            37
2       Chicken Kabab            37
3       Chicken Kadai            37
4         Dal Makhani            37
5 Sai Bhaji and Pulav            37
6          Tava Pulav            37
7          Total Meal            37
```

Which is the total sum of dish_quantity variable. But I want something like this.

```
dish_quant <- df_final %>%
              group_by(dish_name) %>%
              summarize(Dish_Quantity=sum(dish_quantity)) %>%
              arrange(desc(Dish_Quantity))

        dish_name           Dish_Quantity
           (fctr)              (int)
 1       Chicken Kadai            11
 2     Chicken Biryani             9
 3         Dal Makhani             6
 4 Sai Bhaji and Pulav             3
 5          Tava Pulav             3
 6          Total Meal             3
 7       Chicken Kabab             2
```

Where am I doing wrong? I think there's a problem with referencing column name of a dataframe while doing it in Shiny.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are running into problems with [SE/NSE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html). `dplyr` does things a little bit differently, normally you call it with the names of columns, which it does some processing on. But, when using it with a character variable, that magic fails, and you need to fall back on standard evaluation.

To fix it, you need to use the standard evaluation versions of the `dplyr` verbs (they end in `_`), and use lazyeval on your function calls.

Here's a fix for your code, using the builtin mtcars dataset:

```
library(lazyeval) # so we can use interpret
library(dplyr)

var1 <- "cyl"
var2 <- "mpg"
mtcars %>%
    group_by_(var1) %>% #note the _
    summarize_(Sum = interp(~sum(x), x = as.name(var2))) %>% #note the _ and the interp call
    arrange(desc(Sum))

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

    cyl   Sum
  (dbl) (dbl)
1     4 293.3
2     8 211.4
3     6 138.2
```