# R: Dplyr 'group_by' does not seem to work in Shiny

Tags: r, group-by, shiny, dplyr, metafor

I just started experimenting with *Shiny* and I have a problem getting the *dplyr* 'group_by' function to work.

My general idea is that I have a dataset with a number of numerical variables and a variable by which these variables can be grouped (in my case 19 countries, so a variable ranging from 1 to 19). 
Now I want to run a meta-analysis using the *metafor* package on the correlation between two variables for each country.
So I want to calculate the correlation between the two selected variables for each country separately and then put these together in a meta-analysis and finally show a forest plot of these effects.

I have used the mtcars dataset as an example for how far I have come:

**UI**:

```
library(shiny)
library(metafor)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(

    selectInput("x", label = "Choose Variable I", 
    choices = c("Displacement (cu.in.)", "Horsepower", "Rear axle ratio",
    "Weight (1000lbs)", "1/4 mile time"), selected = "Displacement (cu.in.)"),

    selectInput("y", label = "Choose Variable II", 
    choices = c("Displacement (cu.in.)", "Horsepower", "Rear axle ratio",
    "Weight (1000lbs)", "1/4 mile time"), selected = "Horsepower")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
    ) 
  )
```

**SERVER**:

```
 server <- function(input, output) {


  output$plot <-renderPlot({

    data_x <- switch(input$x, 
                     "Displacement (cu.in.)" = mtcars$disp,
                     "Horsepower" = mtcars$hp,
                     "Rear axle ratio" = mtcars$drat,
                     "Weight (1000lbs)" = mtcars$wt,
                     "1/4 mile time" = mtcars$qsec)

    data_y <- switch(input$y, 
                     "Displacement (cu.in.)" = mtcars$disp,
                     "Horsepower" = mtcars$hp,
                     "Rear axle ratio" = mtcars$drat,
                     "Weight (1000lbs)" = mtcars$wt,
                     "1/4 mile time" = mtcars$qsec)

    meta_main <- mtcars %>% 
      group_by(gear) %>% 
      summarise(participantID = n(), 
                correlation = cor(data_x, data_y, use = "complete.obs"))


    meta <- rma(ni=participantID, ri=correlation, 
                method="REML", measure="COR", data=meta_main)


    forest(meta) 

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the example I have grouped by 'gear' (which has 3 levels) and selected the variables 'Displacement', 'Horsepower', 'Rear axle ratio', 'Weight', and '1/4 mile time'.

The final output shows the selection widgets and also the forest plot. 
However, the correlation is the same for all levels of 'gear'. I therefore suspect that the 'group_by' function does not work as intended.

I have tried to use 'group_by_' as suggested online, but it does not change much.

Any ideas on how 'group_by' might work with Shiny?

Comment: did you also use `summarize_` when you tried `group_by_` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481864/dplyr-group-by-not-working-in-shiny?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

try this server function, first you should load `lazyeval` package.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

output$plot <-renderPlot({

data_x <- switch(input$x, 
                 "Displacement (cu.in.)" = "disp",
                 "Horsepower" = "hp",
                 "Rear axle ratio" = "drat",
                 "Weight (1000lbs)" = "wt",
                 "1/4 mile time" = "qsec")

data_y <- switch(input$y, 
                 "Displacement (cu.in.)" = "disp",
                 "Horsepower" = "hp",
                 "Rear axle ratio" = "drat",
                 "Weight (1000lbs)" = "wt",
                 "1/4 mile time" = "qsec")

meta_main <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  mutate(participantID = n()) %>%
  group_by(gear, participantID) %>% 
  summarise_(correlation = interp(~cor(x, y, use = "complete.obs"), x = as.name(data_x), y = as.name(data_y)))


meta <- rma(ni=participantID, ri=correlation, 
            method="REML", measure="COR", data=meta_main)


forest(meta) 

})

}
```

Comment: great! that works. thank you so much, I have been trying that for ages! I need to have a look at the standard evaluation method.

Comment: Note that these methods are now outdated.